# Service-worker 'periodicsync' with self-signed certificate

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, esp32, self-signed-certificate

**Setup:**
I have an ESP32 running a HTTPs-Server with a self-signed certificate. It provides status information about some homeautomation-devices.
Now I built a Vue-based PWA that is served from a public HTTPs-Server with a regular certificate.
The PWA requests data from the ESP in the local network via https://192.168...

After installing the PWA on my mobile device, Chrome warns me that my PWA accesses content from an untrusted-cert https (which is perfectly reasonable for me).
As a workaround I have to do the following (only once): Access https://192.168... in Chrome, where I get the warning for 'NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID' and allow this untrusted access.
After this workaround the PWA works great with the ESP32 even after restarting and updating it.

I want to use the PeriodicSync-API to get the status from my ESP32 once a day and show a notification on my mobile device if something's not ok.
I setup the service-worker to listen for the `periodicsync`-event and then `fetch()` data from the ESP32 via https.

**Problem:**

This works correctly if I connect to my device via `chrome://inspect/#devices` and simulate the 'periodicsync'-event.
But if I leave the app alone for 12-24 hours and the regular `periodicsync`-event is finally triggered then `fetch(...)` catches an error with the following reason: `TypeError: Failed to fetch`

My guess (after spending many hours on that issue) is that this error relates to the untrusted certificate. It seems that chrome remembers that I agreed on the unsafe access as long as the PWA is open but it does not adopt this agreement for the service-worker.

**Question:**
Any ideas how to trust a self-signed-certificate in the service-worker or tell the service worker it should use the same permission as the PWA?

A no-go is:

- starting browser with certain flags
- using a paid long-term-certificate on the ESP32

Comment: Since the security exception doesn't seem to be enough, I'd explicitly add the self-signed CA cert to Android. See these instructions: https://coderwall.com/p/wv6fpq/add-self-signed-ssl-certificate-to-android-for-browsing

Comment: Tried it but unfortunately didn't help.